# Bandwidth Test for HTTPS Proxy Server

Tags: ssl, proxy-server, speedtest, jmeter

Is there a tool that would test bandwidth usage on a server. I've tried siege and Jmeter. Both are very good for direct web applications. However they give support for proxy, siege proxy did not work at all and with jmeter SSL did not work. Also I'm interested in number of concurrent users.

Thank You
Sai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a very large stream video or large file, that is good test for bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can be configured to use proxy for Internet connection. Following command-line arguments are respected by JMeter startup script (jmeter.bat or jmeter.sh) in regards to proxy settings configuration:

```
    -H, --proxyHost <argument>
            Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
    -P, --proxyPort <argument>                                                                                                                                          
            Set proxy server port for JMeter to use                                                                                                                     
    -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>                                                                                                                                      
            Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)                                                                                                        
    -u, --username <argument>
            Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
    -a, --password <argument>
```

ALso it doesn't have any problems with SSL protocol simulation and even recording-and-replay. See [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide for detailed how-to.